# Maven android release:perform problem with distributionManagement

Tags: android, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am using the maven [android-release archetype](https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes/wiki/Android-release-archetype)

After the release:prepare successed, I ran a release:perform and get the following error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project xxx: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter
```

But in my pom.xml I have the following :

```
<distributionManagement>

<repository>
  <id>nexus-releases</id>
  <name>RepositoryProxyRel</name>
  <url>http://server:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>

<snapshotRepository>
  <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
  <name>RepositoryProxySnap</name>
  <url>http://server:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
</snapshotRepository>
```

Could anybody explain what is wrong with my configuration and why I get this error ? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I set the distributionManagement tag after the mvn release:prepare, so the modification was not taken into account. I performed a release:rollback, commited the modification of my pom with the distributionManagement, performed again a release:prepare, and now the release:perform works fine.